# can someone look at my code and perhaps make it shorter

Tags: php, forms

Is there a way to shorten this code? It's for a raspberry pi control panel.  I will be adding the functions later but my main goal now is to make it shorter.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php 
if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $lamp1 = "uit";
    $lamp2 = "uit";
    $lamp3 = "uit";
    $lamp4 = "uit";
    $lamp5 = "uit";
}
else
{
    $lamp1 = $_POST['lamp1'];
    $lamp2 = $_POST['lamp2'];
    $lamp3 = $_POST['lamp3'];
    $lamp4 = $_POST['lamp4'];
    $lamp5 = $_POST['lamp5'];
    if($_POST['submit'] == " Slaapkamer ")
    {
        if($_POST['lamp1'] == "uit")
        {
            $lamp1 = "aan";
        }
        else
        {
            $lamp1 = "uit";
        }
    }
    else if($_POST['submit'] == " Badkamer ")
    {
        if($_POST['lamp2'] == "uit")
        {
            $lamp2 = "aan";
        }
        else
        {
            $lamp2 = "uit";
        }
    }
    else if($_POST['submit'] == " Woonkamer ")
    {
        if($_POST['lamp3'] == "uit")
        {
            $lamp3 = "aan";
        }
        else
        {
            $lamp3 = "uit";
        }
    }
    else if($_POST['submit'] == " Keuken ")
    {
        if($_POST['lamp4'] == "uit")
        {
            $lamp4 = "aan";
        }
        else
        {
            $lamp4 = "uit";
        }
    }
    else if($_POST['submit'] == " WC ")
    {
        if($_POST['lamp5'] == "uit")
        {
            $lamp5 = "aan";
        }
        else
        {
            $lamp5 = "uit";
        }
    }


}

?>
<ul>
    <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Slaapkamer "></li>
    <input type="hidden" name="lamp1" value=<?php echo $lamp1; ?>>
    <li><?php echo 'Slaapkamer licht: '.$lamp1; ?></li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Badkamer "></li>
    <input type="hidden" name="lamp2" value=<?php echo $lamp2; ?>>
    <li><?php echo 'Badkamer licht: '.$lamp2; ?></li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Woonkamer "></li>
    <input type="hidden" name="lamp3" value=<?php echo $lamp3; ?>>
    <li><?php echo 'Woonkamer licht: '.$lamp3; ?></li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Keuken "></li>
    <input type="hidden" name="lamp4" value=<?php echo $lamp4; ?>>
    <li><?php echo 'Keuken licht: '.$lamp4; ?></li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value=" WC "></li>
    <input type="hidden" name="lamp5" value=<?php echo $lamp5; ?>>
    <li><?php echo 'WC licht: '.$lamp5; ?></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

This code will be used in a web based app to control my home.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give you an example of how to shorten things:

```
<?php

$kamers = [
    'Slaapkamer'=>['lamp'=>1,'status'=>'uit'],
    'Badkamer'=>['lamp'=>2,'status'=>'uit'],
    'Woonkamer'=>['lamp'=>3,'status'=>'uit'],
    'Keuken'=>['lamp'=>4,'status'=>'uit'],
    'WC'=>['lamp'=>5,'status'=>'uit']
];

$htmlKamers = '';
$htmlKamers .= '<div>';
foreach($kamers as $kamer=>$data) {
    $lightStatus = isset($_POST['lamp'.$data['lamp']]) && $_POST['lamp'.$data['lamp']] == 'uit' ? 'aan' : 'uit';
    $elemChecked = $lightStatus === 'aan' ? 'checked': '';
    $htmlKamers .=  '<input type="checkbox" name="lamp'.$data['lamp'].'" value="'.$lightStatus.'" '.$elemChecked.'> '.$kamer.' ('.$lightStatus.')<br/>';
}
$htmlKamers .=  '</div>';

?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="lamp1" value="aan">
    <?php echo $htmlKamers;?>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: tnx :) i like this way with the checkboxes